# Flutter SliverAnimatedList with firestore data updated

Tags: listview, flutter, animation, flutter-sliver

My scenario: a team of 5 users are using the app and looking at the same stream of data.  When one user updates the data, the other team members should be informed via a simple animation.

Using SliverAnimatedList I am able to animate when new data is added or existing data being delete using **animationKey.currentState.insertItem** or **animationKey.currentState.removeItem**.

However, when the data value is updated (temperature change from 55C to 60C) I cannot find a way to initiate the animation.

Been banging my head on this for a few day, any pointers and directions are welcome.

Comment: `AnimatedSwitcher` ? or `TweenAnimationBuilder`?

Comment: @pskink, thanks will research into these 2 widget

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I deletee then added the record to animate the change.  Looks pretty good once you get the animation right and coordinate between the delete and add.